# Navigating between different Views from two different Application Projects within a Solution in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, n-tier-architecture

I have a Project going on in which I will have to develop Two Applications. I am using n-tier Artitecture and have following Projects in A Solution

1. DAL
2. BLL
3. BusinessEntities
4. Application1
5. Application2

Now I want to Know How can I navigate between the views of these two Applications Normally we do the following to navigate within an Application

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", OtherStuff..)
```

Now How can I navigate from action of one Application to action in Second Application. 
Thanks

Comment: why dont you try "Areas" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. i usually use areas for handle this.

   ```
       var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {Area = "Myarea"});
       var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {Area = "area2"});
   ```
2. if u like your add other projects like this way u can use Custom ViewEngine.
   in this way first add route rules like this :

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
          name: "app",
          url: "{application}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new {application = "MyApplication1", controller = "Panel", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
   ```

second: 
add virtual paths of ur app :

```
 public class CustomAreaViewEngine : VirtualPathProviderViewEngine
{
    public CustomAreaViewEngine()
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
        "~/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

        };
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Areas/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/{2}/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;
    }
```

and u sould change global.asax :

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomAreaViewEngine());
    }
```

and finally u should implement ur controller in main application namespace.
Do you still need to explain this way?

if u want u can develop CustomAreaViewEngine that can put ur applications to a custom directory like MyModules.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet may be to just put entries in both `Web.Config` files with the root paths of both sites. Not something you'd want to hardcode anyway. Then use those to manipulate the strings that you get from `Url.Action()`, for which you can use any strings you want, it never checks if they actually match with your project.

**Web.config** (reverse entry values for the other site):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyRoot" value="/Site1" />
    <add key="OtherRoot" value="/Site2" />
</appSettings>
```

**Code:**

```
var myRoot = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyRoot"];
var otherRoot = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OtherRoot"];
var url = Url.Action("Bla", "YadaYadaYada");
var otherUrl = otherRoot + url.Substring(myRoot.Length);
```

You might want to create a helper or a singleton class per site etc. to optimize this, but the concept stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, But I think using "Areas" is best solution in my case :)